# How to dynamically feed value to Gmail subject from Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to create a variable for Subject line and feed the same into the Subject area.
As you can see in line 16 where I try to feed value from a cell and line 40 where I want to insert it.

[image]

I have tried various methods, but to no avail.

Comment: Please can you share your relevant code rather than a screenshot

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to see the screen shot, typically a view only sheet is best. Here is a snippet of code from one of my projects:

```
function SendOfferEmail() {
  
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var activeRow = sheet.getActiveCell().getRow();

var strDesk = sheet.getRange(activeRow,1).getValue();
var response = ui.alert('Confirm Desk', "Sending offer for the " +  strDesk + " desk?", ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
if (response == ui.Button.YES) {
  var response = ui.prompt("Paste information from background waiver", ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
  if (response.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.OK) {
    var waiver = response.getResponseText() + " ";
    var FirstName;
    var eMail;
    var Subject = sheet.getRange(activeRow,3).getValue();
    var ccList = sheet.getRange(activeRow,6).getValue() + "," + sheet.getRange(activeRow,7).getValue();
    var lenWaiver = waiver.length;
    FirstName = GetData(waiver, "FirstName:", lenWaiver, "MiddleName:").trim();
    if (FirstName == "") {
      ui.alert("First Name token not found in the BGW information provided, aborting");
      return;
     }
    response = ui.alert('Confirm First Name', "Using first name: " +  FirstName, ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
    if (response == ui.Button.NO) {
      return;
    }
    eMail = GetData(waiver, "Email:", lenWaiver, " ");
    // check for valid email
    if (!isEmailAddress(eMail)) {
      ui.alert("Invalid email address: " + eMail);
      return;
    }
    var aliases = GmailApp.getAliases();
    var fromname = GetUserName(aliases[0]);
    var from = fromname + " OneSupport <" + aliases[0] + ">";
    var id = sheet.getRange(activeRow,2).getValue();
    var body = getGoogleDocumentAsHTML(id);
    // substitute candidate first name for tag
    body = body.replace("&lt;candidate_first&gt;", FirstName);
    // ui.alert(sheet.getRange(activeRow,2).getValue() + "EOD");
    var id = sheet.getRange(activeRow,4).getValue();
    var deskBlob = DriveApp.getFileById(id).getAs("application/pdf"); 
    var id = sheet.getRange(activeRow,5).getValue();
    var newhireBlob = DriveApp.getFileById(id);
    GmailApp.sendEmail(eMail, Subject, body, {
      cc: ccList,
      from: from,
      htmlBody: body,
      attachments: [deskBlob.getAs(MimeType.PDF), newhireBlob.getAs(MimeType.PDF)]
    });
  }
}
}
```

I get the variable from an active row, but getting from a specified range should work just fine as well.

Answer (score 0):

Guys I found this simpler hack -

instead of typing anything in the subject - I just put this:

```js
""+sub+"";
```

And it worked perfectly!